# How to apply conditional formatting across a whole column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So, I am trying to code a macro that will allow me to find a value within a spreadsheet, store it as a variable called "TotalHooks", and then color the values purple in a different column, "Count5s", if they are equal to (TotalHooks - 1). I've gotten it to successfully locate and apply this conditioning to the first cell in the "Count5s" column, but don't know how to get that formula condition to apply correctly to the rest of the numbers in the column. Here's my code:

```
Dim TotalHooks As Integer
Dim StraightLiner As Integer

Cells.Find(What:="TotalHookCount", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0).Activate

TotalHooks = ActiveCell.Value

StraightLiner = TotalHooks - 1

Cells.Find(What:="Count5s", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0).Activate
    If ActiveCell = StraightLiner Then
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a loop which does Find and then FindNext to keep the search going. I have not tested this code but I'd write something along these lines:

```
Dim TotalHooks As Integer
Dim StraightLiner As Integer
Dim row As Long
Dim curCell As Range


Cells.Find(What:="TotalHookCount", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Offset(1, 0).Activate

TotalHooks = ActiveCell.Value

StraightLiner = TotalHooks - 1

Dim cellFound As Range
Set cellFound = Cells.Find(What:="Count5s", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
row = 1
If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
    Do While Not IsEmpty(cellFound.Offset(row, 0))
        Set curCell = cellFound.Offset(row, 0)
        If curCell = StraightLiner Then
        With curCell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent4
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With curCell.Font
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        End If
        row = row + 1
    Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I implemented your code in mine, but I'm still running into issues. "Count5s" is the text header at the top of my column, and is not defined in any other way. I need the code to find the number below that text header, determine if it's a StraightLiner or not, and then move on to the next cell below it and do the same thing. I have a relative range in which this needs to be done, starting from the Offset cell below "Count5s". The first "Set cellFound" condition is throwing an "Object required" error. I'm pretty new to VBA, so thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at a new version of the code I have posted up, You need to search for the header text and then move down matching cells until you hit an empty cell. You need to figure out how the Debugger works so you can fix this stuff.